# Get value from SQLite3 using for loop as a seperate variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, for-loop, nested-loops

I have three values stored inside my `SQLite` Table, i.e. `question-hyperlink`, `excerpt`, `pl8 js-gps-track nav-links--link`. 
I want them to get each value inside a separate variable.

**For example :**

`x = question-hyperlink`,

`y = excerpt` and

`z = pl8 js-gps-track nav-links--link`.

**Here is my code :**

```
import sqlite3

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE Classes (id VARCHAR(30));""")
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO Classes VALUES ("question-hyperlink");""")
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO Classes VALUES ("excerpt");""")
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO Classes VALUES ("pl8 js-gps-track nav-links--link");""")
conn.commit()

cur.execute("""select * from Classes;""")

for class_Names in cur.fetchall():
    print(class_Names)
```

**This gives me :**

```
('question-hyperlink',)
('excerpt',)
('pl8 js-gps-track nav-links--link',)
```

I have tried nested loops for this but failed. How to get them a seperate variable as listed in the example above?

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try the following:

```
all_values = tuple()
for class_Names in cur.fetchall():
    # let's merge all tuples into one
    all_values += class_Names
# then we can upack the tuples into different variables
x,y,z = all_values
```